# JS - Array (Fuse 2 arrays into one)

Tags: javascript, arrays

Alright so I stuck on the code reading docs. 
Iam starting with JS so go easy one me =].
I've got and array calld `Area`
which contains few arguments

```
let Area = ["Kanig Village", "Fort Chune", "Shadowy Heights", ...];
```

I cannot change this array till specific part of my code is executed but after I wish to add to every position another value. How to I do that to get exacly like that :

```
let Area = ["Kanig Village 14:30", "Fort Chune 15:30", "Shadowy Heights 16:30", ...];
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you get the new values from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I THINK this is what you want to do:

https://jsfiddle.net/wxzrpjeL/

```
//Declare 2 arrays
let Area = ["Kanig Village", "Fort Chune", "Shadowy Heights"];
let b = ["1", "2", "3"];

//Execute a function for each element in the Area array
Area.forEach(function(val, i) {
//The function appends a space, and the corresponding element in the second array
      Area[i] += " " + b[i];
});

// just to illustrate the result, throw the result to the screen as a string...
alert(Area.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope this is your answer

```
let Area = ["Kanig Village", "Fort Chune", "Shadowy Heights"];
for(i=0;i<Area.length;i++)
  {
    var hour=14+i;
    Area[i]+=" "+hour+" : 30";
  }
```

Comment: Beware [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Declare your variables. :-) *(Disclosure: That's a post on my anemic little blog.)*